# External js file not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to move all my jquery to an external file however it is not working. I am calling the external file after everything else but the jquery functions are not working. I think it may be because i have more than one function with `$(function() {` however not being proficient with jquery i do not know how to tackle this. Below is a sample of what i am trying to move over.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    jQuery("#textsizer a").textresizer({
        target: "#size"
    });
});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $("#crime").validate();
    $.validator.messages.required = '<span style="color:#FE2E2E">&nbsp;Required</span>';
});
</script>
```

I am thinking i need to only have one with `$(function() {` but i don’t know what to correctly replace it with or if this is the reason the external file is not working?

Comment: is jQuery & the required plugins loaded correctly ?

Comment: I don't think there will be a problem with multiple $(function...) calls, are you seeing any JavaScript errors on the page?

Comment: You can have as many `$(function() {..})` as you want. Make sure that you don't include the `<script ...>` tags in the external files and that you include them after jQuery.

Comment: jQeary and the plugins are loading without any problems. I am not seeing any errors other than the functions wot working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove the `<script>` tags if it is in an external .js file.

Comment: That was it, i completley forgot to take them out! Thank you thebjorn and Felix Kling

Answer (score 0):

Stick this in an external file that is included in the html document after jquery and it's plugins:

```
$(function() {
    $("#textsizer a").textresizer({
        target: "#size"
    });

    $("#crime").validate();
    $.validator.messages.required = '<span style="color:#FE2E2E">&nbsp;Required</span>';
});
```